# Fast memory access in C++?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

What should I take in consideration when developing a game in terms of fast memory access in C++?

The memory I load is static so I should put in in a continuous block of memory right?

Also, how should I organize the variables inside structs to improve performance?

Comment: If you have to ask questions like these, you better focus on features and high-level design instead of guessing around at low-level details since you likely won't achieve much anyway. And even if you knew what you were doing on that level, (1) performance has lower priority to actually stuff anything done and (2) these are micro-optimizations, which by their nature yield only tiny improvements.

Comment: Is your question about actually improving the speed with which you access the memory or about the overall efficient design of the various aspects (allocation, deallocation, segmentation etc.) of your memory management module?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Memory Performance* is extremely vague.

I think that what you are looking for is about handling the CPU Cache as there is a factor of about 10 between an access in the cache and an access in the main memory.

For a complete reference on the mechanisms behind the cache, you might wish to read this excellent serie of articles by [Ulrich Drepper on lwn.net](http://lwn.net/Articles/252125/).

In short:

*Aim at Locality*

You should not jump around in memory, so try (when possible) to group together items that will be used together.

*Aim at Predictability*

If your memory accesses are predictable, the CPU will likely prefetch the memory for the next chunk of work, so that it is available immediately, or shortly, after finishing the current chunk.

The typical example is with `for` loops on arrays:

```
for (int i = 0; i != MAX; ++i)
  for (int j = 0; j != MAX; ++j)
    array[i][j] += 1;
```

Change `array[i][j] += 1;` with `array[j][i] += 1;` and the performance varies... at low optimization levels ;)

The compiler should catch those obvious cases, but some are more insidious. For example, the use of Node Based containers (linked lists, binary search trees) instead of array-based containers (vector, some hash tables) may slow down the application.

*Don't waste space... beware of false sharing*

Try to pack your structures. This has to do with alignment, and you might be wasting space due to alignment issues within your structures, which artificially inflate the structure size and waste cache space.

A typical rule of thumb is to order the items in the structure by decreasing size (use `sizeof`). This is dumb, but works well. If you are more knowledgeable about the size and alignments, just avoid holes :) *Note: only useful for structure with lots of instances...*

However, beware of false sharing. In Multi Threaded programs, concurrent access to two variables that are close enough to share the same cache line is costly, because it involves a lot of cache invalidation and CPU battling for cache line ownership.

**Profile**

Unfortunately, this is *HARD* to figure out.

If you happen to be programming on Unix, `Callgrind` (part of the Valgrind suite) can be run with cache simulation and identify the parts of the code triggering the cache misses.

I guess that there are other tools, I just never used them.

Answer (score 6):

You don't care. Such things are likely to be micro-optimisations of the smallest nature. Get it working first, if it's too slow then find out which parts are slow, and optimise those (hint: It is likely to be the way you call libraries etc, not memory-access).

Comment: +1. "Premature optimization is the root of all evil." -- D. Knuth

Comment: @DevSolar –1 if I could. Organizing memory access is **not** a premature optimisation in many cases.

Comment: @DevSolar: You can easily make you program ten times slower by accessing memory in such way you induce multiple cache misses. Now add page file and you no longer talk about optimization like this.

Comment: The OP cares: else he would not ask this question on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with earlier statements.  You should write your game, then figure out where time is spent and try to improve there.

However, in the spirit of providing some potentially helpful [and potentially distracting from real issues :-)] advice there are some common pitfalls you might find:

- Function pointers and virtual methods provide a lot of design flexibility, but if they are used very, very frequently you will find them to be slower than things which can be inlined.  This is mostly because it's harder for the CPU to perform branch prediction on calls through a function pointer.   A good mitigation for this in C++ is to use templates, which can give you similar design flexibility at compile time.
  One potential downside to this approach is that inlining will increase your code size.  The good news is that your compiler makes the decision of whether or not to inline, and it can likely make better decisions about that than you can.  In many cases your optimizer knows about your specific CPU architecture and can make some good guesses appropriate for that.
- Avoid indirection in your frequently accessed data structures.

For example this:

```
struct Foo
{
   // [snip] other members here...

   Bar *barObject;  // pointer to another allocation owned by Foo structure
};
```

can sometimes create less efficient memory layouts than this:

```
struct Foo
{
   // [snip] other members here...

   Bar barObject;  // object is a part of Foo, with no indirection
};
```

It may sound silly and in most cases you won't notice any difference.  But the general idea is that "needless indirection" is a good thing to avoid.  Don't go too much out of your way to do it, but it's something to keep in mind.

One potential downside to this approach is that it could make your `Foo` objects no longer fit neatly in cache...

- Along the lines of the previous two bullets...  In C++, the STL containers and algorithms can lead to some pretty efficient object code.  In the case of `<algorithm>`, your functor passed to various algorithms can easily be inlined, helping you avoid unnecessary pointer calls while still allowing generic routines.  In the case of containers, the STL can appropriately declare objects of type parameter `T` inside of list nodes etc., helping to avoid unnecessary indirection in data structures.
- Yes, memory access can make a difference...  An example would be looping through pixels in a large image.  If you process the image column-at-a-time, it can be worse than processing line-at-a-time.  In the most common image formats, the pixel at (x, y) is typically next to the one at (x + 1, y), whereas the pixel at (x, y) is typically (width) pixels away from (x, y+1).
- Along the same lines as the second bullet, one time working on a project with image manipulation (though on old hardware by today's standards) I saw that even the arithmetic involved in determing the location of a pixel was causing a slowdown.  For example if you're dealing with coordinates (x, y), an intuitive thing to do is to reference a pixel at `buf[y * bytes_per_line + x]`.  If your CPU is slow at multiplication and your image is large, this can add up.  In this circumstance it's better to loop line-at-a-time than it is to keep computing the location of (x, y) for various coordinates.

Of course, the overall design of your game should drive your early decisions, and measurement should guide your performance refinements.  You shouldn't go out of your way to implement these bullet points if it keeps you from getting "real work" done or makes the project harder to understand.  But, these bullet points are meant to provide some examples of where you might see some trouble, and introduce some context on what can cause performance issues in practice, aside from other measures such as algorithmic complexity.

Comment: On modern CPUs (I guess starting from 4th generation of Intel Core i7) non-inline function calls are faster than inline, I guess this is so because branch prediction mechanism starts processing the body of the function in parallel with the code calling it. You can test it with a loop incrementing a `volatile` variable vs. incrementing the same `volatile` variable in a `virtual`/DLL/`__declspec(noinline)` function.

Answer (score 0):

Finding a solution before you have a problem is not productive.

It is better that you concentrate on your design leaving such details for later, who knows, maybe you will end up never having any performance issues due to a good overall design.

Answer (score 0):

memory usage does not have to be contiguous.  if you can halve the size of memory used, that might help a bit.

In terms of struct organization, you should keep bytes together, then shorts together, and so on.  Otherwise, the compiler will waste memory aligning smaller bytes and shorts to double word locations.

one other tip.  if you are using a class, you can put it on the stack, instead of allocating it with new.

i mean

```
CmyClass x;

instead of 

Cmyclass px = new CmyClass;
...
delete px;
```

**edit
When you call new() or malloc you call into the C++ heap, sometimes the heap returns a new block of memory in a few cycles, sometimes it doesn't.  When you declare a class on the stack, you still eat up the same amount of memory (maybe more complicated than that) but the class is just 'pushed' on the stack, and no function calls are required.  ever.  When the function exits, the stack is cleaned up and the stack shrinks back.

Comment: Could you elaborate why class on stack is better than on heap?

Answer (score 0):

An address read from cache is much faster than when read from main memory. So try to keep any addresses that you are reading in close succession as close to eachother as possible.

For example when building an linked list, you will probably be better off mallocing one big block for all your nodes (which can be placed more or less in order) than using one malloc per node (which may well fragment your data structure)

Comment: I think data location predictability is actually more of the issue than tightly packed data. A contiguous block in which you jump around will still probably introduce a lot of overhead. Fixed stride access (array-like) for example is predictable and can therefore be prefetched by the CPU.

Comment: Provided all your data fits into the cache, you can jump around as much as possible. When new data needs to be fetched, the oldest cache line is evicted, if you then go back to the evicted memory, you need to refetch the data from main memory.

Comment: True, but a cache line is typical less than a kibibyte, which is actually not that much. So at best you have a full list of 256 integers, in most cases however you will already be split over 2 cache lines. Data predictability takes into account that you can hit the same cache (in which case it won't do a thing). Random hopping strongly depends on cache association.